# DB2 start sequence with Select from table

Tags: db2, sequence, increment, db2-luw

I am using this sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ORG_SEQ
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 NO MAXVALUE
 NO CYCLE
 CACHE 24;
```

I am trying to make the sequence start with a specific number which I receive from a select statement, however it does not work because it always needs a numeric signed literal.

Does anybody know an alternative?

I tried the solutions from other posts however they do not work on my DB2.

Thank you.

*I use Linux a a DB OS

Comment: What error message and error code do you get when you use the syntax `alter sequence ... restart with  ...`.   You should never write "does not work" because it tells us nothing.  Always write your Db2-server version and operating-platform when you ask for Db2 help because the answers can depend on that information.

Comment: I receive:"SQL0104N  An unexpected token "ALTER SEQUENCE RESTART WITH SELECT MA" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<create_proc>".  SQLSTATE=42601"

Comment: Your syntax is not valid. What is your Db2-server operating-system (Windows/Linux, i-series, Z/OS ) ?

Comment: Linux is the OS which is used

Comment: ...okay, **why** do you want to do this?  It's terribly brittle (sequences aren't really meant to be dynamically rebased, and you're in lots of trouble if there's _an_y concurrent access happening).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
begin
  declare newmax int;
  set curmax = select max(whatever) from sometable;
  execute immediate 'alter sequence your_seq restart with ' || curmax+1;
end
```

Comment: My code looks like this and it did not work. I receive SQLSTATE=42601 
 CREATE SEQUENCE ORG_SEQ
     START WITH 1
     INCREMENT BY 1
     NO MAXVALUE
     NO CYCLE
     CACHE 24;
----------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
     LANGUAGE SQL
begin
  declare newmax int;
  set curmax = select max(PARP_ID) from S0NCSTR.S0NRP50D003;
  execute immediate 'alter sequence ORG_SEQ restart with ' || curmax+1;
end

Answer (score 0):

DB2 does not allow sub-selects or parameters for a [`CREATE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004201.html) or [`ALTER`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004200.html) statement on a sequence. You can see on the charts that it only allows `numeric-constant`.

```
>>-ALTER SEQUENCE--sequence-name-------------------------------->

   .-----------------------------------------------.   
   V  (1)                                          |   
>----------+-RESTART--+------------------------+-+-+-----------><
           |          '-WITH--numeric-constant-' |     
           +-INCREMENT BY--numeric-constant------+     
           +-+-MINVALUE--numeric-constant-+------+     
           | '-NO MINVALUE----------------'      |     
           +-+-MAXVALUE--numeric-constant-+------+     
           | '-NO MAXVALUE----------------'      |     
           +-+-CYCLE----+------------------------+     
           | '-NO CYCLE-'                        |     
           +-+-CACHE--integer-constant-+---------+     
           | '-NO CACHE----------------'         |     
           '-+-ORDER----+------------------------'     
             '-NO ORDER-'
```

The best option you would have would be to run your SELECT, and then build the create or alter from the result (e.g., using string concatenation).

Comment: I did the following, but received the same error 42601: CREATE SEQUENCE ORG_SEQ
     START WITH 1
     INCREMENT BY 1
     NO MAXVALUE
     NO CYCLE
     CACHE 24;

CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE idValue INTEGER ;
SET idValue = 6;
ALTER SEQUENCE ORG_SEQ RESTART WITH idValue;

Comment: Again... you **can't use a variable** with altering/creating sequences. It has to be a **numeric constant**. A variable is not a numeric constant. Execute immediate like @mustaccio said in another answer would work. Or building the SQL string using app code. Or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If your Db2-database runs on Linux , you need to run two statements to rebase the sequence.

The first statement finds the next value for the sequence by using select max() on the column in the target table that relies on the sequence.
The second statement alters the sequence.

You can either use a script (for example in bash), or you can use a stored procedure (in SQL PL) or compound-SQL.

Below I show a simple bash script , to run *locally* to the database, which rebases a sequence.

If your database is remote then you need to modify the connect syntax to specify a userid and password.

The user that runs this script must have suitable rights to query the table and perform the alter sequence.

```
#!/bin/bash
    #
    # Rebase a sequence in a local Db2 database


    typeset +i next_value=0
    typeset    database=your_db_name
    typeset    table_name=your_table_name
    typeset    base_schema=the_name_of_your_schema_that_contains_the_table
    typeset    column_name=the_name_of_the_column_that_uses_the_sequence
    typeset    seq_name=your_schema.your_sequence_name



    db2 connect to ${database}
    (( $? != 0 )) && print "Failed to connect to database" && exit 1

    next_value=$( db2 -x "select coalesce(max(${column_name},1)+1 from ${base_schema}.${table_name} " )
    (( $? > 2 )) && print "Failed to query ${base_schema}.${table_name}" && exit 1


    db2 -v alter sequence ${seq_name} restart with ${next_value}
    (( $? != 0 )) && print "Failed to alter sequence" && exit 1

    db2 -v connect reset
```